# too many file descriptors in select() python in windows

Tags: python, asyncore

i am trying to receive about 1000 connections to my server but it cannot receive more than 512. What can i do to increase the amount of open connections? I am running windows 8.1

Not: I am very new to this stuff so, thanks for help

Here is my code;

```
import asyncore
import socket
import uuid
import time
import threading

class statistics(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            entry = raw_input("")
            zaman = int(time.time())
            cmd = receivedCmd
            print "calculating.."
            time.sleep(1)
            if entry == 'istatistik':
                print str(receivedCmd-cmd) + " command/second"
                print "total received commands: " + str(receivedCmd)
                entry = ""
class tcpClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clientid = uuid.uuid1(int(time.time()))
        self.buffer = ""
        self.buffer_size = 0
        self.conn_time = time.time()
        self.overflow = 0
        #print str(self.clientid) + " assingned"
    def recv_msg(self, msg):
        global receivedCmd
        self.buffer = msg
        self.buffer_size = len(self.buffer)
        receivedCmd = receivedCmd + 1
        if self.buffer_size >= 1024:
            self.overflow = 1

    def __del__(self):
        print str(self.clientid) + " has left."


class TCPHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    global clist
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(1024)
        if data:
            if clist[self].overflow:
                self.send("overflow")
                self.handle_close()
            else:
                self.send(data)
                clist[self].recv_msg(data)
    def handle_close(self):
        del clist[self]
        self.close()

    def handle_error(self):
        del clist[self]
        self.close()

class TCPServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    global clist
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        self.clist = clist
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is None:
            pass
        else:
            sock, addr = pair
            #print 'Connection : %s' % repr(addr)
            clist[TCPHandler(sock)] = tcpClient()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clist = {}
    receivedCmd = 0
    server = TCPServer('', 5000)
    server2 = TCPServer('',5001)

    StaticsThread = statistics()
    StaticsThread.start()
    asyncore.loop()
```

Note: I still cannot receive more than 512 connections with the Twisted Framework, i don't know what to do. There have to be thousands of connected clients. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asyncore` module relies in the `select` OS function, which only supports a limited number of file descriptors.

As an alternative use a multi-threading server (I won't recommend this) or, better, the [Twisted framework](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) which is event-driven (highly recommended!).

Hope this helps!

---

Since Twisted's default reactor under Windows is also select-based then you should consider using the IOCP reactor instead.

```
from twisted.internet import iocpreactor
iocpreactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor
```

But also take into account that Twisted prefers Linux systems (where the default reactor is epoll-based) rather than Windows. Maybe switching to Linux is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into it. I tried threading but threads are limited as well

Comment: i tried it but twisted framework didnt work either. still stuck at 512 connections :(

Comment: Yes there is no problem in linux but this has to work in most operating systems. I will check out the code i hope it ll work this time. Thanks again